# Why PWA ServiceWorker don’t work for me with Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, offline, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am having great difficulty in operating the ServiceWorker with ionic 2.
I start a new project with ionic this:

`$ Ionic start pwa-project blank --v2`

The default structure created by the ionic me two important folders:
    - src
    - www

In both there are the files:
- Index.html (where I have to uncomment the call to service-worker)
- Manifest.json (which set up the data from my app)
- Service-worker.js (the my service worker itself)

The logic for developers in ionc is not touching anything in the **www** folder and only work in the **src** folder. And I did, ran the `$ ionic serve` and started to edit my html, service-worker and manifest, all in the **src** folder. But I noticed that the changes are not reflected on the same files in the **www** folder.
Restarted the `$ ionic serve` and nothing happened.

All right, then I proceeded to edit these three files directly in the **www** folder to Activate from my service-worker.

This time I came across another problem. The service-worker does not run.
The script invokes the service-worker in the index.html file prints to the console the success message **"service worker installed"** confirming that it was installed, but I wrote some `console.log()` in my service-worker of events and these events are not fired, and I can not say why.

```
console.log ( '[SERVICE WORKER] Install');
console.log ( '[SERVICE WORKER] Activate');
console.log ( '[SERVICE WORKER] Fetch');
```

None of these is displayed on the console, which makes me believe that the service-worker for some reason, is not running.

In Chrome DevTools, Application pane, appears that the service-worker is installed and enabled.

Has anyone experienced this problem? Managed to solve?

PS .: When I create a project in vanilla javascript everything works fine, the service-worker is installed, running and messages are usually displayed on the console, which makes me believe that there is any interference Ionic (v2).

My Ionic info is:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
OS: Distributor ID: elementary OS Description:  elementary OS Freya 
Node Version: v5.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for my current setup, all is working fine:

```
cli packages: (/home/khophi/Developments/Ionic/KhophiPwa/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    Node              : v7.10.1
    npm               : 4.2.0 
    OS                : Linux 4.10
```